# Not all control paths return a value in my bool check

Tags: c++

I actually check all the participants and still can't find where it is missing the return value.
Thanks for who look through my codes <3

```
bool Time::check()
{
    if ((month < 1) || (month > 12)) return false;
    switch (month)
    {
    case 1:case 3:case 5:case 7:case 8:case 10:case 12:
        lastday = 31;
        if ((day <= lastday) && (day > 0)) return true;
        else return false;
        break;
    case 4:case 6:case 9:case 11:
        lastday = 30;
        if ((day <= lastday) && (day > 0)) return true;
        else return false;
        break;
    case 2:
        if ((year % 4) == 0)
        {
            lastday = 29;
            if ((day <= lastday) && (day > 0)) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        else
        {
            lastday = 28;
            if ((day <= lastday) && (day > 0)) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In that snippet, it's exactly what the compiler says. There's a `return` statement missing in the end (`return true;` i assume).

Comment: Your compiler probably can't tell that there is no possible month that does not return

Comment: The compiler seems to ignore the `if ((month < 1) || (month > 12)) return false;` when considering control paths. Replacing this with a `default: return false;` at the end of the `switch` should remove the warning and keep the behavior equivalent.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Note: Logically, the range check at the beginning means the `default` can never occur. But frankly, it would be simpler to just remove the range check and put that behavior in the `default` case, and you'll educate the compiler for free.

Comment: Note that whenever you find yourself writing something like `if (condition) return true; else return false;` you can simplify it to just `return condition;`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Of course, in this case the `switch` `case`s should probably just define `lastday` then `break`, and have a single line at the end (outside the `switch`) of just `return day <= lastday && day > 0;`. Only the `default` case would directly return `false`. Repeating the same check against `0` and `lastday` logic four times is nuts.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're right, I didn't notice the condition was always the same.

Comment: @ShadowRanger "*Only the `default` case would directly return `false`*" - or, it could just set `lastday=-1` and then `break`, letting the final `return day <= lastday && day > 0;` return `false`. So that there is only 1 `return` in the function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yeah, I mention that in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71427053/364696) as an option (`0` would work too, even if `day` is `unsigned`, since `day > 0` is also tested), but it feels ugly to pretend non-months have a meaningful concept of `lastday` just to avoid multiple `return`s. I find it cleaner to say "The case where we're not a month is immediately not valid", rather than pretending it is in a way that later checks will then treat as invalid.

Answer (score 3):

The big problem: Your compiler isn't smart enough. Sure, logically, it's impossible for the function as written not to return, but the compiler isn't tying together the preliminary range check with the `switch` to realize any code that reaches the `switch` will *always* match one of the cases.

The simplest solution is to just get rid of the manual range check and have it handled by the `switch`'s `default` case, e.g.:

```
bool Time::check()
{
    switch (month)
    {
    // Original cases here

    default:          // added
        return false; // added
    }
}
```

The code could be improved further by avoiding code duplication; the *only* thing differentiating your `switch` `case`s is `lastvalue`. So limit them to that, and put the common code outside the `switch`:

```
bool Time::check()
{
    int lastday; // Declared outside the switch so it's available for final test
    switch (month)
    {
    case 1:case 3:case 5:case 7:case 8:case 10:case 12:
        lastday = 31;
        break;
    case 4:case 6:case 9:case 11:
        lastday = 30;
        break;
    case 2:
        lastday = year % 4 == 0 ? 29 : 28; // Note: Leap year rules are more complicated than this; look 'em up
        break;
    default:
        return false; // Not a valid month; could do lastday = 0; break; to stick to a single return but that's liable to confuse
    }
    return day <= lastday && day > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler tries to understand your code, but not always it can understand everything. A different code with similar issue is:

```
int foo(int x){
    if (x <= 1 || x >= 3) return false;

    if (x == 2) return true;
}
```

Either `x` is `2` or `x` is not `2`, then it is either `<= 1` or `>= 3`. Hence the function always returns. Nevertheless, the compiler issues a warning:

```
<source>:6:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
```

Consider this obfuscated version which is maybe similar to what the compiler uses for that anlysis:

```
int foo(int x){
    if (some_condition) return false;

    if (some_other_condition) return true;
}
```

If neither `some_condition` nor `some_other_condition` is `true` the function does not return and that is undefined behavior.

Long story short, The compiler is clever, but not clever enough to see that you are covering all possible values for `month`. To fix it remove the initial `if` and add a `default` case instead. Or rather move everything common to all cases outside of the switch:

```
bool Time::check()
{
    int lastday = 0;
    switch (month)
    {
    case 1:case 3:case 5:case 7:case 8:case 10:case 12:
        lastday = 31;
    case 4:case 6:case 9:case 11:
        lastday = 30;
        break;
    case 2:
        if ((year % 4) == 0)
        {
            lastday = 29;
        }
        else
        {
            lastday = 28;
        }
    default: lastday = -1;
    }

    return ((day <= lastday) && (day > 0));
}
```

---

I would suggest to move the logic to find days per month out of the function `check`. And you can use an array:

```
int days(int month,int year)
{
    int days_per_month[] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,30,31,30,31};
    return days_per_month[month-1] + (month==2 && year%4==0);
}
```

Comment: `(month==2 && year%4==0)` is easier to understand but still incorrect.  `(month==2 && isLeap(year))` is what is needed.

Comment: @BenVoigt as incorrect as OPs leapyear algo. Though I agree on the `&&`